# Access encoded I, P, and B frames separately using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding

I am working on a video delivery project using ffmpeg. I want to see whether it is possible to separate encoded frames based on their type (I, P, B). For example, if I encode a 5s long .yuv video using ffmpeg, I have a 5s long .mp4 file. Is it possible to store all P-frames in this newly generated .mp4 file in a separate file (without the need to actually playing it back) in some way? The goal is to have the I-frames and P-frames separately delivered from one node to another and reassemble them. I agree that this sounds very similar to SVC with temporal scalability but let's assume that that is not an option.

Comment: This sounds like a very custom  solution and not something that would be built into FFMPEG, but something you would have to build yourself.

Comment: This may be theoretically possible. But do the piecemeal meals have to be valid MP4 structures? In any case, it'll take many commands.

Comment: Thanks, so the bottom line is that I need to modify the source code, right?